# Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: ios, swift, double, cgfloat

I was trying to move a UIView based on UIPanGestureRecognizer velocity and for that I wrote this code and I am getting the error at this line

***var duration: NSTimeInterval = yPoints / velocity***

and this is the portion of the code

```
let velocity = pan.velocityInView(self.superview).y
var yPoints: CGFloat = 100.0
            var duration: NSTimeInterval = yPoints / velocity
            var offScreenCenter: CGFloat = self.superview!.frame.origin.y
            offScreenCenter += yPoints
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {() -> Void in
                self.superview!.frame.origin.y = offScreenCenter
            })
```

Can I get this converted to Double ? or need to change the code ?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I a new with swift and may need time to understand things. if you know what to do You could have answered rather making a hint. Thanks...

Comment: Please try with `var duration: NSTimeInterval = Double(yPoints / velocity)`

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks even a little bit late I did the same with my code now.